# How to generate X-Auth-Token and X-Seller-AuthZ-Token on Snapdeal

Tags: node.js, api, e-commerce

I have tried to generate the X-Auth-Token and X-Seller_AuthZ-Token on snapdeal. I have used this below link for generating the tokens:

https://authorize.snapdeal.com/authserverui/login?returnURL={ReturnURLAddress}&appId={SellerEmailID}

But it gives Invalid appId/partnerId/partnerName in query params.

Comment: @Michel if you have any idea about my query then Please tell me. From last 6 months I have tried to generate the X-Auth_Token and X-Seller_AuthZ_Token on Snapdeal.

Comment: Are there any special characters in either of these strings? Are you URL encoding them? Have you contacted Snapdeal for help? I have no experience with them.

Answer (score 1):

Provided link is use for X-Seller-Authz generation

Add your appId in the URL. appId must have been shared with you by our product team when you registered with snapdeal.

appId : After successful partner registration,snapdeal provides the ApplicationId and X-Auth-Token .

returnURL=http://www.abcd.com

For Documentation => http://sellerapis.snapdeal.com/docs/api-authorization